# my getJSON code doesn't work in jquery 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, getjson

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I just wonder why my getJSON code doesn't work with jQuery 1.4.2, it worked smoothly with jQuery 1.3.2 though

So here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td.hps_ajax a').click(function() {
        id = this.id.replace(/.*hps_ajax/,'');
        if(confirm('Anda yakin mau menghapus record ini?'))
            $.getJSON('../admin/media_admin/ajaxHapus/'+id, remove_row);
        return false;   
    }); 
})

function remove_row(data) {
    if(data.sukses == '1') {
        $('td.hps_ajax a#hps_ajax'+data.id).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow',function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    } else {
        alert('Gagal menghapus File.');
    }
}
```

The getJSON link is a CodeIgniter App Link. Anyone know why this doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Can you append a sample json response your url generates when called? Most likley it is simply invalid json

Comment: "doesn't work" three times? Seriously?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most likely cause if your JSON is not completely valid, this is now checked in jQuery 1.4+

[From the docs](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14):

> jQuery 1.3 and earlier used JavaScript’s eval to evaluate incoming JSON. jQuery 1.4 uses the native JSON parser if available. It also validates incoming JSON for validity, so malformed JSON (for instance {foo: "bar"}) will be rejected by jQuery in jQuery.getJSON and when specifying “json” as the dataType of an Ajax request.

Use something like [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to validate/fix your JSON, it should start working once valid.  Take the response from `'../admin/media_admin/ajaxHapus/'+id` and check it on JSONLint, you can also view it with [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) which is handy.

Comment: thanks nick for the reply. i already try paste my code in jsonlint.com for validation. but it keeps tell me that parser failed.

Comment: @Nikolius - Can you post the JSON?

Comment: this is my return json

{'sukses':'1','id':56}

Comment: @Nikolius - Your JSON should be double quotes to be valid, like this: `{"sukses":"1","id":56}`

Comment: @Nick - Thank you nick, finally can get it work with jquery 1.4.2. :D

Answer (score -1):

getJson in jquery 1.4 not fire.
Here is an example to solve this problem:

```
//begin ( in jquery 1.3.2)
$.getJSON("/url",{id: 'xyz'}, function(json){
     //alert('');
}




// change to ( in jquery 1.4.1)

$.ajax({url: "/url",
  dataType: "text",    // notice: not type : JSON
  success: function(text) {
    json = eval("(" + text + ")"); 

    // do something with JSON
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Why would you do this? Why not use jQuery's built-in parsing, which is very good?